# Parse HTML with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, html-parser

I have an html document that I need to scrape for certain strings. The document is a youtube playlist. For example:

```
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL11CE9468C379D2C8"))
```

When I view the HTML source code I can see the string I want.

```
<tr class="pl-video yt-uix-tile " data-title="Tyler The Creator - Yonkers" data-video-id="XSbZidsgMfw"
```

The string is what follows `data-video-id` in quotations. In this playlist there are 7 videos so there are 7 samples of this code, each with a different `data-video-id`. How can I loop through and save each of these strings to a `@scraped_id` variable?

The id is saved using

```
 @video = @stream.videos.find_or_initialize_by(url: @scraped_id)
 @video.save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CSS selector to pick out all elements that have a `data-video-id` attribute, and then take the value of that attribute.

```
doc.css("[data-video-id]").each do |el|
    @scraped_id = el.attr('data-video-id')
    @video = @stream.videos.find_or_initialize_by(url: @scraped_id)
    @video.save
end
```

Comment: You could also just use regex and avoid Nokogiri all together, this regex will find all the IDs you want: `/data-video-id="([^"]*)"/`

Comment: It can identify the id but for some reason it rolls back the database after each load and does not save the record. Does this have to do with the loop it is in?

Comment: No that'll be some other, unrelated issue